# How can we access list data of SharePoint Online through the Java API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, java-api

We have running SharePoint online application and Java API user need to fetch the data of list of SharePoint online. How can we access these data through the Java API?

Answer (score 1):

I guess one option is using JSON where you can access lists and items with calls like

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ourList')/items
```

- Where `company` is your tenant name
- and `ourSite` is your site collection (if not the root SC)
- and `ourList` is the list you're trying to get

More to read: [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

If you don't fancy JSON you could always consume web services 'the old fashion way' described in [Java Tip: Consuming SharePoint web services with a Java client](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html)

Comment: Thanks for Reply. However, we need use the client ID and secrete ID for authentication to the SharePoint site...